# What does mean "new List()" notation?

Tags: java, collections

What does exactly mean following notation?

```
List<Integer> list = new List<Integer>(){...}
```

Can I say that I create an instance of interface `List<E>`? Rather not, because we can't create new instance of any interface in Java.

Below there are all methods that must be overwritten by this notation.

But I don't understand exactly which methods must be overwritten. They aren't all methods either from `List<E>` or Superinterfaces of List - `Collection<E>, Iterable<E>`

(there is no e.g. `hashCode()` method (if they are all List's methods) or e.g. `parallelStream()` method (if they are all inherited methods from List's Superinterfaces))

```
List<Integer> list = new List<Integer>(){

        public boolean add(Integer e) {...}
        public void add(int index, Integer element) {...}
        public boolean addAll(Collection<? extends Integer> c) {...}
        public boolean addAll(int index, Collection<? extends Integer> c {...}                                 
        public void clear() {...}
        public boolean contains(Object o) {...}
        public boolean containsAll(Collection<?> c) {...}
        public Integer get(int index) {...}
        public int indexOf(Object o) {...}
        public boolean isEmpty() {...}
        public Iterator<Integer> iterator() {...}
        public int lastIndexOf(Object o) {...}
        public ListIterator<Integer> listIterator() {...}
        public ListIterator<Integer> listIterator(int index) {...}
        public boolean remove(Object o) {}
        public Integer remove(int index) {...}
        public boolean removeAll(Collection<?> c) {...}
        public boolean retainAll(Collection<?> c) {...}
        public Integer set(int index, Integer element) {...}
        public int size() {...}
        public List<Integer> subList(int fromIndex, int toIndex) {...}
        public Object[] toArray() {...}
        public <T> T[] toArray(T[] a) {...} 

};
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`new List<Integer>() { ... }` is an annotation used to create an instance of an anonymous class that implements the `List<Integer>` interface.

The methods that you must implement are all the methods that don't have implementation in the `List` interface or its ancestor interfaces. All the methods of the `Object` class (such as `hashCode()`) have implicit implementation in all interfaces. Other methods may have default implementations if you are using Java 8 (I'm assuming that's the case for `parallelStream()`).

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to create a list of known value? In that case you need an implementation of List, like this:

```
  List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<Integer>(Arrays.asList(1, 2, 3));
```

To create an empty list, it would just be:

```
  List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<Integer>();
```